# Login.php Redirect To Members.php Not Working

Tags: php, redirect

I have a login, register page. The register page is working fine, but I have a problem with my login page. When I log in succesfully it is supposed to redirect me to a page called members.php but instead just stays on the same page and goes no where. Here is my code for the login.php page where I think the problem may be occuring:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
if (isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) {
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];
    $pass     = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        if ($pass != $info['password']) {
        } else {
            header("Location: members.php");
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
    if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
        die('<h1 class="error"></h1><p>You missed something</p>');
    }
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if ($check2 == 0) {
        die('<h1 class="error"></h1><p>That user does not exist in our database</p>');
    }
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        $_POST['pass']    = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
        $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
        $_POST['pass']    = md5($_POST['pass']);
        if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
            die('<h1 class="error"></h1><p>Incorrect password, please try again</p>');
        } else {
            $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $hour              = time() + 3600;
            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour);
            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);
            header("Location: members.php");
        }
    }
} else {
?> 

<h1 class="login"></h1>

<form action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 

<p>Username</p><input type="text" class="username" name="username">

<p>Password</p><input type="password" class="password" name="pass">

<div><button type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">Log in</button></div>

</form> 

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: can you provide your php script we can not see it from given website

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10391424/892493  I think you should put `exit;` after all of your header redirects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in this line:

```
 if ($pass != $info['password']) {
        }
```

Its telling the script to do nothing if the password doesn't match. Try putting a message there, like:

```
 if ($pass != $info['password'])
 {
    die('invalid login');
 }
```

If that doesn't work, put echo statements throughout your page, so you can follow what happens through the execution. i.e, `echo 'checking login <br />', echo 'login checked..<br />'` etc.

On another note, you should definitely encrypt your password, don't store it in plain text or if your website ever gets hacked (its happened to many big names) they will have everyone's password in plain text.

Also, by putting `$username` exactly how it is inside your query, you can be leaving your site open to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), I suggest you read up on it if you don't want to be hacked.

Comment: It didn't work it just doesn't redirect to the members.php page. I know man, but it just a simple script for users to access different parts of the website :) No personal information is going to be stored. Thank you for your answer but it didn't work :(

Comment: @user1366805 you need to put in echo statements throughout the code to see what happens when you run the script

Answer (score 0):

First try declaring your own variables instead of re-initializing the built-in variables, for instance $_POST['pass']    = md5($_POST['pass']);
to $pass    = md5($_POST['pass']);

Comment: Hello. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Cheers.